# How do I display foreign languages in my php file

Tags: php

When I try to display letters of a foreign languages in my php file they show up as "?".

Anybody have any ideas how I can display them properly?

If I save the file as a HTML it displays the letter properly.

Comment: use UTF8 in your editor. and save files in this encoding

Comment: Yes, you should read up on character encodings (and use UTF-8 throughout your solution).

Comment: Do you mean in the actual PHP file, or in the web browser when you open the PHP file?

Comment: Is this in the editor? Use a different editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+Using   charset=utf-8

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>
</head>
<body>
<body>
</body>
```

++ If you mention about open your php file .you have use an editor that support utf-8 something like this.

I am using Eclipse .

Comment: I am using notepad++ and like I mentioned it saves alright as HTML but as php or inc; it is not so successful.

Comment: you can test with notepad to save your code ->click save ->encoding->choose which one you used in your code example (utf-8)

Answer (score 2):

To add support for foreign characters you need to use UTF-8 (or any other similar encoding but UTF-8 is the most widely used) encoding.

**text editing**

At first you need to have your PHP/HTML files in UTF-8 encoding, use a text editor that supports this encoding, just check that the editor doesn't prepend UTF-8 BOM symbols to the file.

**PHP**

To serve your PHP files as UTF-8 (so the browser doesn't get mixed up about this) add relevant header

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/html; Charset=UTF-8"); ?>
```

**HTML**

To serve your static HTML pages as UTF-8 use appropriate meta tag

```
<!-- with HTML5 -->
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<!-- or with older HTML formats -->
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**MySQL**

To save/load UTF-8 encoded text in MySQL use the following statement after connecting to the MySQL server

```
<?php
mysql_connect(...);
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
?>
```

but check that the tables have also appropriate encodings set